# Beamer output without frames

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to get `beamer` to output the contents of the frames without the actual frames. The idea is to have the handouts produced as normal A4/Letter papers. I already have my content arranged in sections, subsections and proper itemization etc.

Comment: This sounds like you want the `article` mode; have you read Section 21 (particularly 21.2) in the beamer manual?  If not, try reading that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why you put this as a comment instead of an answer though.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would be helpful to you or not, so it was more a speculative "Have you tried ..." than an attempt at answering.  It sounds as though this is what you were looking for, is that right?

Comment: Yes. It was exactly that. I would have preferred a simpler solution but I guess that's the one I have to use.

Please put that as an answer (preferably with an example from the manual) so that I can mark it accepted. For future reference, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you want the `article` mode which is a way of incorporating the `beamer` frames into a normal LaTeX article.

The details of how to use it are in Section 21 (particularly 21.2) in the [`beamer` manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).